# Python dictionary syntax to initiate a dictionary

Tags: python

Could anyone let me know the following Python syntax?
How do I interpret the following Python dictionary?

```
graph["start"] = {}
# Map "a" to 6
graph["start"]["a"] = 6
```

Does it initiate an Array and assign the dictionary as its element?
or it initiated a map with "start" as the key and dictionary as the value?
or the variable name is graph["start"] and it's type is a dictionary?
I just got confused

Comment: This code by itself just throws a NameError. The `graph` variable is never defined.

Comment: Also note, Python variables are not typed.

Comment: After looking in the source code. In the file, the first line is graph = {}. So the graph has been defined as a dictionary. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume 'graph' has been defined as a dictionary already.
Here's a small example:

```
graph = {}
graph['a'] = {}  # The key is 'a', it references a dictionary.
graph['a']['b']=2  # In this new dictionary, we'll set 'b' to 2.
print(graph) #{'a': {'b': 2}}
```

You've got your syntax right. :-)
I also didn't think arrays existed in Python...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that previous code has bound the variable "graph" to a dictionary.  Then:

```
graph["start"] = {}
```

adds to "graph" a key:value pair where the key is "start" and the value is a new dictionary.

The line:

```
graph["start"]["a"] = 6
```

looks up the object stored in "graph" under the key "start", and adds to it a new key:value pair where the key is "a" and the value is 6.

The two lines together are the equivalent of:

```
graph["start"] = {"a":6}
```

or

```
graph["start"] = dict(a=6)
```